# C Strings: Simple Question

Tags: c++, c, string

I have three variables initialised below :

```
char c1[] = "Hello";
char c2[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char* c3 = "Hello";
```

I am aware that c1 and c2 are the same, and that they are both strings because they are terminated by \0. However, c3 is different from c1 and c2. Is this because c3 does not terminate with a \0? Does that mean that c3 is not a string? If c3 is not a string, then why does    `printf("%s", c3);` not give an error? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Is there a reason why c1 and c2 can be modified but c3 can't?

Comment: Why do you need to set c3 as a pointer, just out of curiosity?

Comment: What led you to the conclusion that the "Hello" pointed to by `c3` doesn't end with `\0`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In terms of C, the most pertinent difference between `c3` and the others is that you are not allowed to attempt to modify the underlying characters with `c3`. I often find it helpful to think of it like this:

```
char *xyz = "xyz";
```

will create a modifiable *pointer* on the stack and make it point at the non-modifiable character sequence `{'x','y','z','\0'}`. On the other hand,

```
char xyz[] = "xyz";
```

will create a modifiable *array* on the stack big enough to hold the character sequence `{'x','y','z','\0'}` and then copy that character sequence into it. The array contents will then be modifiable. Keep in mind the standard says nothing about stacks but this is commonly how it's done. It is just a memory aid, after all.

Formally, `c3` is a pointer to a string literal while `c1` and `c2` are both arrays of characters which both happen to end with a null character. When they're passed to functions like `printf`, they decay to a pointer to the first element of the array which means they'll be treated identically to `c3` within that function (actually they decay under quite a few circumstances, see third quote from c99 below for exceptions).

The relevant sections of C99 are `6.4.5 String literals` which explains why you're not allowed to modify what `c3` points to:

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.

and why it *does* have a null terminator:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.

And `6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators` under `6.3 Conversions` states:

> Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: `When they're passed to functions, they decay to a pointer`. In context of C++, `c1` and `c2` can be passed by reference also, in which case they still will not decay to a pointer. It depends on how function receives it.

Comment: You say that "*"you're not allowed to modify `c3`"*. Isn't it more precise to say that "you are allowed to modify the pointer `c3` but not the string that it points to" ?

Comment: @ypercube, you're right. I got it right in the first para then got sloppy. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

First point,

```
char* c3 = "Hello"; // may be valid C, but bad C++!
```

is an error prone style, so don't use it. Instead use,

```
const char* c3 = "Hello";
```

It's a valid code. Pointer `c3` points to the address of the location where `"Hello"` string is stored. But **you cannot modify** `*c3` (i.e. content of `c3`) as earlier cases (if you do so, it's an undefined behavior).

Comment: @iammilind thanks! that makes sense. btw, is there any reason c3 can't be modified while the other 2 can?

Comment: The pointer `c3` **can** be modified. The string that `c3` points to is not safe to be modified.

Comment: Careful with your language, "deprecated" has a specific meaning in ISO standards and this feature is _not_ deprecated in either c99 or c1x. Contrast that with `gets` for example, which was deprecated in c99 and removed from c1x.

Comment: Interesting - it was deprecated in C++03, but no longer. Phew - there's a lot of code out there that assign string literals to non-const char pointers.

Comment: @pax: So is `char*p = "foobar";` allowed or forbidden in C++0x?

Comment: Don't know for sure, @Fred, I'm more a C man myself. But I have a hard time believing they'd make a fundamental, seriously breaking change like that.

Answer (score 3):

`c3` is a pointer to a string, which is what `printf("%s", ...)` expects as its argument.

The reason that `printf("%s", c1)` or `printf("%s", c2)` would also work is because in C arrays 'decay' to pointers very easily in expressions.  In fact, about the only times that an array name doesn't decay into a pointer in an expression is when it's used as the operand to the `sizeof` operator or the operand to the `&` (address-of) operator.

This leads to common confusion that pointers and arrays are equivalent in C, which is not correct.  It's just that in C arrays can be used nearly everywhere pointers are. One exception is that they can't be assigned to, except when they're subscripted (which turns out is an expression that treats them as a pointer).

Note that there's one other difference in the last string - since it's a sting literal, it cannot be modified (it's undefined what will happen if you try).
`

Answer (score 1):

`c1` and `c2` allocate 6 bytes of memory and store the null-terminated string in it.

`c3`, however, allocates the (also null-terminated) string in *program* memory, and creates a pointer to it, i.e., the string is stored with the other instructions rather than on the stack (or heap? someone correct me) so editing it would be unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

In C, the constant `"string"` can have two meanings, based on which context it is used. It can either denote a string in the `ro` section of the executable (though I don't think the standard spells that out), making `const char *foo = "bar"` a statement initializing `foo` to point to a location in the loaded executable's memory. If the binary blob (`"bar"`) is indeed in the `ro` section, and you do something like `foo[0] = 'x'`, you'll end up with a `SIGSEGV`.

However, when you write `char x[] = "Hello"` (or `char x[6] = "Hello"`), you're using `"Hello"` as an array initializer (like `int x[2] = { 1, 2 }`), and the `x` is just a regular (writable) array allocated on the stack. In this case, `"Hello"` is just a shorthand for `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }`.

Both `"bar"` and `"Hello"` are null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

`c3` is not terminated by a NUL or a NULL.  It is a pointer to a string terminated by a NUL.

Comment: What is the difference between NUL and NULL?

Comment: `NUL` is the ASCII term for the '\0' character. I typically see "NULL" used more often.  it's probably more correct to simply say "null character" since the identifier `NULL` is defined in `stddef.h` (and other headers) and is used for the null pointer constant.

Comment: @Michael Burr: Thanks. I know and use the null pointer constant, but what exactly is it? isn't it also the integer value `0`?

Comment: @Mr. TAMER: I didn't mean to imply that you (or anyone else) weren't aware of what `NULL` was used for in C source, just that when talking about string termination, it's probably not the best term to use (though I don't think it's all that confusing in practice, and I use it that way myself quite often).  And it's usually defined as something like `((void*) 0)` in C and simply `0` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

<s>It is a string</s> It points to a string, but it is risky.

Comment: @iammilind: Mistake acknowledged!

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to a string with different termination.

Comment: And What is that different termination?

Answer (score 0):

C3 is a pointer to the first cell at the string.
C1,C2 are just a regular array that aren't pointed by someone.