# Assigning string literals to char*

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, deprecated, string-literals

Is the following code legal, deprecated or illegal in C++0x?

```
char* p = "foobar";
```

I originally asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488715/c-strings-simple-question/6488744#6488744) as a comment.

Comment: It continues to work and continues to be poor style.

Comment: GCC 4.6 says "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*".

Comment: well, it should be `const char*`, to be more correct

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The conversion

```
char* p = "foobar";
```

is deprecated in C++98/C++03, and has been removed (that is, §4.2/2 removed) in C++0x.

So, the code is **not valid** in C++0x.

However, MinGW g++ 4.4.1 still only emits a warning, not error.

> **C++98/C++03 §4.2/2** (which is removed in C++0x):
>
> ---
>
> A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `char`”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to `wchar_t`”. In either case, the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an rvalue. [Note: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D. ] For the purpose of ranking in overload resolution (13.3.3.1.1), this conversion is considered an array-to-pointer conversion followed by a qualification conversion (4.4). [Example: `"abc"` is converted to “pointer to `const char`” as an array-to-pointer conversion, and then to “pointer to `char`” as a qualification conversion. ]

Comment: Even g++ 4.4.5 with `-std=c++0x` only emits a warning.

Comment: So §4.2/2 was originally about string literal to `char*` conversion, I suppose? Would be cool if you could include that paragraph from the C++03 standard as a quote, if possible :)

Comment: @Fred: I added the paragraph from C++03. @Alf: I hope that's Ok with you.

Comment: @Alf: Actually I copied it straight from the C++03 standard, not from the C++98 one. If you're sure it's the same as in C++98 your change won't hurt, but if it got changed, it's now wrong.

Comment: @sbi: it's the same in original C++98.

Comment: +1, I have rechecked the standard and it does actually list this as a difference between C and C++: §C.1.1 [diff.lex] contains the example: `char* p = "abc"; // legal in C, illegal in C++`. The rationale for the change is: *This avoids calling an inappropriate overloaded function, which might expect to be able to modify its argument.*

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is now illegal in C++0x. C++03 had a special caveat for this conversion for legacy code, but C++0x removed it and now you are violating const correctness.

Of course, I don't know if any real compilers have removed it, but they would be well within their rights.