# Bus Error on fopen()?

Tags: c++

I am using Totalview to debug some code, and it is stopping with a Bus Error.

What is this, and how do I fix it? here is the code snip

In my main:

```
    char *infilename = "/home/dcole/Images/lena1024s.jpg";

    /* Try opening a jpeg*/
    if( read_jpeg_file( infilename ) > 0 ) 
    {   
       //do some stuff    
    }
```

The function:

```
int read_jpeg_file( const char *filename )
 {
         /* these are standard libjpeg structures for reading(decompression) */
         struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
         struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
         /* libjpeg data structure for storing one row, that is, scanline of an image */
         JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];

         FILE *infile = fopen( filename, "rb" ); //this line is where the debugger stops with a Bus Error
         unsigned long location = 0;
         int i = 0;

         if ( !infile )
         {
                 printf("Error opening jpeg file %s\n!", filename );
                 return -1;
         }
         return 1;
 }
```

The file I am passing in does exist. I can see that it shows up as the right sting to the full path in the debugger.

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger?  Which line does it error out?  Also, can you show the call to read_jpeg_file and the initialization/allocation of the filename parameter?

Comment: Have you tried running it through e.g. valgrind to check for memory corruption?

Comment: Sure - and yes, I have stepped through it with Totalview. It has a memory checker built in

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. Does it still blow up if you strip it down to just the two important lines (the filename declaration and the fopen)?

Comment: Converting a string literal to `char*` (rather than `char const*`) is deprecated and dangerous. Please don't do it.

Comment: Try running the code for a simple file opening function by removing all the structure declarations. Opening the file might not be the exact problem

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal Please dont spread the MS way of putting const keyword

Comment: @Ulterior: I'm sorry? "The MS way"? This is the consistent way.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal whats wrong with `const char*`, why in the world would you want it `char const*`. MS also allows `const char const *` which is ridicullous

Comment: @Ulterior: Consider `char const* const`. `const` applies to the left, except when there's nothing there in which case it applies to the right. `const char* const` is just confusing. Why not be consistent and always put it where it's supposed to be?

Comment: @Ulterior please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492410/assigning-string-literals-to-char

Comment: Your problem very likely lies outside of the code that you have shared with us. Try incrementally stripping bits and pieces out of your large program until either a) you have a minimal, complete program that still fails or b) your program begins to work. In the first case, please post that program here. In the 2nd case, you've probably found your bug in the deleted text. See http://sscce.org for more details on this technique.

Comment: You have a memory overwrite somewhere outside this code. Can you use this TotalView thingy to find it?

Answer (score -1):

I think you're having a memory access problem because of the filename variable...
Instead of:
char *infilename = "/home/dcole/Images/lena1024s.jpg";

try using: 
char infilename[] = "/home/dcole/Images/lena1024s.jpg";

Comment: Yes, I know its supposed to be the same thing but it is a deprecated operation and you have this warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’. And a bad string pointer sent to fopen() gives this kind of 'bus error' message...

Comment: It's a kind of magiiic :) However this syntax thingy solves the error not. The OP is in for some heavy debugging unless TotalView can act like Valgrind. Also, I can't edit my vote any more, so you can just hope someone else votes you up.

Comment: don't worry, I don't really care about a few points... but by experience I know that often the question is posted from memory and not by copy/past of the code so there are some errors on it and by posting this kind of answer it will make the programmer think about it and get back to the good track, etc... that's the magic of it... ;-)