# how does a pointer stores a string in memory in c

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

```
char *p = "hello";  
printf("%c",*p); //output would be ***h***
printf("%s",p);  //output would be ***hello***
```

At line 2 why we have to use `*p` to `print` a `char` and at line 3 we have to use `p` to `print` a string.

Also at line 1 how the string is stored in memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18479996/1814023

Comment: `const char *p = "hello"` or `char p[] = "hello"`. A `char *p = "hellp"` is a segfault waiting to happen. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492410/assigning-string-literals-to-char), for example.

Comment: take `'*p'` out of `'char*p'` and you get `'char'`, i.e., the first `'printf'` receives a char, now take `'p'` from `'char*p'` and you get `'char*'`, i.e., the second `'printf'` receives a char pointer, don't know if this is by design

Answer (score 2):

an array is simply a pointer to a block of memory filled sequentially with items of a specific type.

`p` in this instance is a pointer to the first character in that array,

`*p` will dereference the pointer, which will return the item at that specific location (i.e. the first character in the string.

The most common string representation in c (and the one used by `%s`) is null-terminated strings. I.e. the string will start at `p` and continue until it hits a null (`\0`) value.

Answer (score 1):

`"hello"` is saved in a read only memory of your system

`p` is a pointer that it is pointing at the beginning of your `"hello"` memory. so it's pointed in the first element of the memory.

`*p` return the content of the memory which `p` is pointing on. and `p` is the address of the first element of the `"hello"` memory so `*p` will return `'h'`

Answer (score 1):

String are stores in memory by a chain of of characters and are terminated by a 0 character.
For example, if you have a string literal "Hello", that string would be stored in memory as a char* array of {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}.

Because of this, if you access the array ( *array ), you only access the first character of the array. You can loop through the array until you find the \0 - char to know where the string ends.