# How to access pointer within a nested structure

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct, char

suppose I have a code like this in C programming language

```
typedef struct up {
    char *str;
} up;

typedef struct up_cont{
    up at;
}up_cont;
```

I have defined `up_cont real;`. I have done all allocation and all!

Now I want to store `"Hello"` in string. I am trying

```
 up_cont real;
*(real.at.str) = "Hello";
```

and its not working!!

And please also suggest how to print it!!

Comment: Just `real.at.str = "Hello";` if it is C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `typedef` goes like below

```
typedef struct up_cont{
    up at;
}up_cont;
```

(more of a typo for above snippet I believe)

---

The answer to your problem is, `str` is a pointer itself. Just use

```
 real.at.str = "Hello";
```

---

EDIT:

> *And please also suggest how to print it!!*

Just the normal way you print any other *string*. Use

```
 printf("str contains %s\n", real.at.str);
```

You can read more about `printf()` [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf)

---

FOOTNOTE:

<sup>FWIW, if you use assign a string literal to a pointer, it will be read-only, you cannot alter the contents. If you want a modifiable *string*, you need to</sup>
<sup>1. Allocate memory dynamically using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family</sup>
<sup>2. Copy the *string literal* using  [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to the allocated memory</sup>

Comment: This is [not valid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492410/assigning-string-literals-to-char) because the literal is a `const char*`

Comment: @CoryKramer It is valid In `C`. and I thought `typedef` is invalid (usage) `C++` style. I see this code as more of `C`.

Comment: Fair enough, I have redacted my -1, I just wanted to be clear about that since the OP tagged C++. I removed their C++ tag to avoid confusion in the future if anyone else sees this post.

Comment: @CoryKramer You are very true, Most of the people believe `C` and `C++` are interchangeable and by changing `printf()` to `cout<<`, a `C` code becomes `C++` (don't laugh, I personally know such peoples.)

Comment: I am just playing and learning!! can you please tell me if I want to create an array of strings in up structure. How could I allocate memory for rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct up_cont{
    up at;
};
```

In C you are not typedefing anything here.
You meant:

```
typedef struct up_cont{
    up at;
} up_cont;
```

Then access it like:

```
up_cont *p = /* ... */;
p->at.str = "hello";
```

As some other mentioned, in C++, you need a `const char *` member in your structure to have a pointer to a string literal (`char *` is OK in C).

Comment: yeah thnx my mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to access the nested struct members is as you have it:  `real.at.str`.

What is invalid is that you are dereferencing `real.at.str`.  The assignment

```
  real.at.str = "Hello";
```

will work, by assigning the left hand side to be the address of the first character in the string literal.

Bear in mind that modifying the string gives undefined behaviour

```
  real.at.str[0] = 'B';
```

since it attempts to overwrite the first character of the string literal `"Hello"` (which is actually a compile time constant) with the character `'B'`.